# Post increment with pointers in while loop in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I am writing the `strcat` function

```
/*appends source string to destination string*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char srcstr[100], deststr[100];
    char *psrcstr, *pdeststr;

    printf("\n Enter source string: ");
    gets(srcstr);
    printf("\n Enter destination string: ");
    gets(deststr);

    pdeststr = deststr;
    psrcstr = srcstr;

    while(*pdeststr++)
        ;
    while(*pdeststr++ = *psrcstr++)
        ;

    printf("%s", deststr);
    return 0;
}
```

For `srcstr = " world"` and `deststr = "hello"` I get `hello`, when I expect to see `hello world`, which is what I see if I change the first `while` so

```
while(*pdeststr);
    pdeststr++;
```

why can't I write all in one line in the first `while`, just like in the second `while`?

Comment: OT: Do not never use `gets()`. It's unsafe and not even C any more. Use `fgets()` instead,

Comment: Another nice example, why doing only *one* thing at *a* time is the preferred way to go.

Comment: Maybe `strcpy( pdeststr, psrcstr );` instead of `while(*pdeststr++ = *psrcstr++);` ?

Comment: Because `while(*pdeststr++);` will increment the pointer even when the `nul` terminator was found. The following "copy" line will then leave that original `nul` terminator where it was, and be useless for string handling functions

Comment: Thanks about gets(), I am reading a book on data structures in C and it is what is used.

Comment: Burn the book, get a good book. There's just **no** excuse for `gets()`.

Comment: @Hugo in this fast-moving world, please use the most up-to-date material you can find.

Comment: Nitpick: the `while (*pdeststr);` loop in the 'it works' version has a stray semicolon.  It either never loops if the string is empty or loops 'forever' if not. Remove the first of the two semicolons.

Comment: @alk *Another nice example, why doing only one thing at a time is the preferred way to go.* Indeed. Sometimes I think the `++` and `--` operators need to be eviscerated from C - they don't really buy anything other than saving textbook writers a few lines of code.  Trying to stuff as many operations into one line of code just to prove you can write "clever" code is in fact a really, really bad coding style.

Comment: *why can't I write all in one line in the first `while`, just like in the second `while`?*  Why do you *want* to write it "all in one line"?  What exactly does that gain you, outside of bugs you don't understand?

Answer (score 5):

Your one line loop

```
 while(*pdeststr++);
```

Is equivalent to

```
while(*pdeststr)
    pdeststr++;
pdeststr++;
```

Because the postincrement operator is executed before the condition is tested, but after the value for the test is determined.

So you could cater for this with

```
 while(*pdeststr++);
 pdeststr--;
```

Comment: This: "*the postincrement operator is executed before the condition is tested, but after the value for the test is determined.*" is a possible explanation, but not necessarily true. Incrementing the variable is a *side effect* of the `++` operator, side effects **will** be carried out until the next sequence point is reached. If `++` is after its operand, the expression evaluates to the value *before* incrementing. But you don't know the exact sequence of events like "testing the condition" ;)

Comment: Typo: unnecessary `;` so possible infinite loop. And I believe it is undefined exactly when the post-increment occurs.

Comment: It would be truer to say "the **pre**increment operator is executed before the condition is tested".

Comment: @WeatherVane "undefined exactly"? ;) I'd word this as "not exactly defined", but yes, that's it. IOW, in the area between two sequence points, don't ever assume anything about the state of a side effect happening there.

Comment: @FelixPalmen sorry about my poor English ;) I meant "undefined **exactly when** . . ."

Answer (score 4):

Mandatory introduction: **do not use gets(), use fgets()!**.

Your problem is here:

```
while(*pdeststr++)
    ;
```

The side effect of incrementing is carried out in your last iteration step (when `pdeststr` points to the `NUL` terminator), so after this loop, `pdeststr` points **one after** your `NUL` terminator. Write it like this instead:

```
while(*pdeststr) ++pdeststr;
```

Answer (score 4):

The boolean value for the `while` condition is computed before the `++` post-increment.

So when your while loop exits, the post-increment operator is executed one last time, hence `pdeststr` is pointing right after the null terminator `char` that follows the word `"hello"`.

Then the rest of the program appends more data after that null `char`. You end up with the string `"hello\0world\0"`. The print function thinks the string ends at the first null `char` it encounters.

Comment: I was writting my conclusion and then I saw your answer, happy to confirm my conclusion, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra incrementation that point you after the `NULL` char, and so finally you could print only the first string.

Comment: `NULL` isn't the same as `NUL`. What you want here is `NUL`.

Comment: Or use the C notation `\0` :)

Comment: @WeatherVane: But that's <tm> You then, isn't it?

Comment: @alk agreed the `'\0'` is better. I meant if you are using a word to describe `0`.

Comment: @alk I thought about that as well. It doesn't really matter ... but `NULL` is misleading at best.

Comment: @alk but in code terms, I prefer to use `0` as a string terminator. I know we should make things clear for our followers, but in a former life no-one ever dumbed down engineering drawings for the benefit of the inexperienced.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Although formally it's not, I'd consider `char s[1]; s[0] = NULL;` as wrong. There is no reason ever to write such code.

Answer (score 1):

By [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) the postfix increment operator (`ptr++`) is **higher** than the indirection (dereference) operator (`*ptr`). Therefore the

```
while(*pdeststr++);
```

will always increment the `pdeststr` first then evaluate the previously pointed value. As an outcome, when the result of evaluation is `0` the `pdeststr` actually points to the **next** element, so there will be a null-terminator character (`'\0'`) between your concatenated words.

As a one-liner solution with `while` loop you can use the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) as follows:

```
while(*pdeststr && pdeststr++);
```

The code snippet above will stop when `*foo` results `0` and won't evaluate the `foo++` part.

Comment: Precedence has nothing to do with always carrying out side effects.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that at the end, `deststr = "hello\0 world\0"` and because of that `printf("%s", deststr);` find the first `\0` and gives as output `hello`